# Применение border-radius в SVG-объектах с D3.js

Tags: style, d3.js

Я применяю border-radius, он отображается в инспекторе, но не применяется. Как решить эту проблему?

HTML перед скриптом -

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url(background.png);
        background-color: #c7b39b;
        border: 1px solid #509111;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #5b992b;
        border-radius: 16px;
        font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
        text-transform: capitalize;

    }

    </style>
<title>shit </title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class='importData' >
</div>

var rects = canvas.selectAll('rect')
                  .data(entries)
                  .enter()
                  .append('rect')
                  .attr('height', 50)
                  .attr('width', function (d) { return d.value * 2;})
                  .attr('y', function (d, i) {return i * 80 ;})
                  .attr('stroke', 'pink') 
                  .attr('border-radius', 3)
```

Comment: можете в вопросе дать `HTML` кусок кода то же?

Comment: Обновил. importData - контейнер для SVG

Comment: Вот я дал в ответе пример, наверное понадобиться

Comment: Действительно, вопрос решён. Спасибо большое!

Comment: не забудьте плюс и птичку на ответ)))

Comment: Мне говорят, что пока не будет 15 баллов, то мои голоса не влияют на рейтинг :(

Comment: Я уже поставил тебе 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример добавления `radius` атрибутов в элемент `rect` с помощю библиотеки `D3.js`:

```js
d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .append('rect')
    .style("width","100px")
    .style("height","100px") 
    .attr("rx", '20')
    .attr("ry", '20');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

`svg` элемент `rect` не имеет атрибут `border-radius`.